# How did Bon Scott die?

Tags: rock, singers

The title says it all. How did Bon Scott die? On the Wikipedia, all it says is he died. But how did it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon_Scott#Death

End of 4th block states the official cause of death was acute alcohol poisoning.